# PHP redirect syntax utilizing results of mysqli query

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a database table with six records which are urls for six different shiny servers. There is a program that populates, on a real time basis, whether each of the servers are available.  I have written a query that returns the url of the first available server.  I have tested the script and determined the selection process works.  I now want to perform a redirect to the available server using the "header" function and I am having difficulty determining the correct syntax.  The URLs are in the format of "muscle.mysite.com:3535nameScan."  Here is what I have at present.

```
$q = "SELECT url FROM ShinyServers WHERE Availability = '1' LIMIT 0, 1 ";

$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
//printf ("%s\n", $row["url"]);

 $url= printf ("%s\n", $row["url"]);

 header ("Location: $url");  //redirect to muscle*

 mysqli_close($dbc);

 exit();  //before or after mysqli_close?  I think after.
```

When I execute, I see mysite.com/40 in the address bar and I get a 404.

I tried this:

```
header ("Location: $row");  //redirect to muscle*
```

When I execute, I get "mysite.com/array in the address bar and I get my 404 page. I have tried many variations and I have thoroughly confused myself.

I hope you can see what I am trying to do.  I have backed up to what does work which is

```
$q = "SELECT url FROM ShinyServers WHERE Availability = '1' LIMIT 0, 1 ";

$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

printf ("%s\n", $row["url"]);

mysqli_close($dbc);
```

I get the first url that is available and I can see the results printed as `muscle.mysite.com:3535nameScan`.  Now, I need to capture the results as a variable I can use in an UPDATE query and the header function.  I have been searching for an answer and I have not found one as yet.  I thought a different fetch command would be the answer but I could not find one that would apply to what I want to do.

I believe I am heading in the correct direction my using the suggestion to use "sprintf."  However, I am still not able to "update" the table.  Here is where I am at now.

```
   error_reporting(E_ALL);

$q = "SELECT url FROM ShinyServers WHERE Availability = '1'  LIMIT 0, 1 ";  //make query

$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);


//printf ("%s\n", $row["url"]);

$url= sprintf ("%s\n", $row["url"]);  //assign results to a variable?

echo "$url";

$qu = "UPDATE ShinyServers SET Availability = 0 WHERE url = $url LIMIT 1";

$ru = mysqli_query($dbc, $qu);

if (mysqli_affected_rows ($dbc) ==1){

echo '<p> The status has been updated</p>';

}else{

echo '<p class="error"> The status could not be updated</p>';

}
```

I get the expected results from 'echo "$url";'  But I am getting the error message "The status could not be updated."  I have been at this for so long I am afraid I am overlooking something.  Is there a problem with the code or could there be a problem with the DB table? I looked at the DB table, created by someone else, and I noticed it does not have a unique column.

With prodigitalson and Dan08's help, I have a script that works. It is as follows

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$q = "SELECT url FROM ShinyServers WHERE Availability = '1'  LIMIT 0, 1 ";  //make query

$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//printf ("%s\n", $row["url"]);

$url= sprintf ("%s", $row["url"]);  //assign results to a variable

//echo "$url";

$qu = "UPDATE ShinyServers SET Availability = 0 WHERE url = '$url' LIMIT 1";

$ru = mysqli_query($dbc, $qu);

if (mysqli_affected_rows ($dbc) ==1){
    echo '

The status has been updated

';

}else{
    echo ' The status could not be updated

';

}

mysqli_close($dbc);

header ("Location: http://$url");

exit();

My DB table is updated and I am redirected (I know I do not need the conditional statement).  I learned also that the "header" function had to be after mysqli_close.  I found that in the php manual. A little more tweaking and then I have the task of marrying this script into a registration script and a login script.  Whoppee...thanks again.

Comment: Stop using `@` to suppress errors

Comment: Part of your problem is [`printf()`](http://php.net/printf) sends output to the browser (which will cause `header` to fail) and returns the length of the string outputted, so `$url` doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: That is good feedback.  I was not sure that it would work but I am at the point where I am trying different things.  I start with  just                     header ("Location: $row");  //redirect to muscle*

Comment: Yeah you want `sprintf` which returns the formatted string, not `printf` which outputs it like `print`/`echo`... You also dont need to worry about closing `mysqli` here because it should close as part of PHP shutdown.

Comment: I tried $url= sprintf ("%s\n", $row["url"]);  then used the variable $url in my query like this:   mysqli_query($dbc, "UPDATE ShinyServers SET Availability = 0 WHERE url = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($url)."' LIMIT 1");   It did not work.  I got the "printf" but the table was not updated.

Comment: Okay, I may have made some progress but I am still missing something.  I think your approach has me going in the right direction.  Take a look at my update.

Comment: Put single quotes around `$url` in your update query (also, you probably don't want that newline character in `$url`. Better yet, use prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Why do you have a LIMIT in your UPDATE query?? Do you have multiple rows with the same url?? Seems like that should be a unique key rendering LIMIT irrelevant.

Comment: I am forever grateful dan08!  That fixed the problem.  What a relief!

Comment: @Learner Even though that solved your problem, I would strongly suggest exploring parametrized queries and prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks again Dan.  I know I need to learn about prepared statements...I am just not there yet and I needed to get this done.  When I am completely finished with this current project, I need to go back and teach myself about prepared statements.      I also want to take a moment and thank prodigitalson for pointing me in the right direction.  You all are super!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is my final script and it works perfectly

```
<?php

//selecting available server and update status
include_once '../DB/test1DB.php'; //connect to DB

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$q = "SELECT url FROM ShinyServers WHERE Availability = '0'  LIMIT 0, 1 ";  //make query

$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$url = sprintf("%s", $row["url"]);  //assign results to a variable

$qu = "UPDATE ShinyServers SET Availability = 1 WHERE url = '$url' LIMIT 1";

mysqli_close($dbc);

header("Location: http://$url");

exit();
```